# Metoerjs naked domain redirect

Tags: meteor

How is it possible to do naked domain redirects from example www.domain.com to domain.com with MetoerJS.

My app is hosted on modulus.io. They don't offer cpanel integration and don't have an option to do this on their end.

My DNS and domain is under GoDaddy and my understanding is that this needs to be done via the hosting provider.

Answer (score 4):

Just got some great help from the guys at differential.io

your going to want to use https://github.com/project-ricochet/meteor-canonical

Comment: Thanks! I have just installed canonical with [`mrt add canonical`](http://atmospherejs.com/package/canonical). I set a `ROOT_URL` like `https://example.com` on my modulus.io project, and also set auto-SSL redirect. I have a `CNAME` set up on `www.example.com` to go to the `project-num.onmodulus.net` URL.  Unfortunately, when I browse to `http://www.example.com`, I get an untrusted certificate warning - it redirects to `https://www.example.com`, not `https://example.com`.  Did you have this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Just found the answer to my question - just turn off modulus.io's auto-SSL redirect! `canonical` redirects to a secure page already.

Comment: Who is your DNS / Domain provider? I'm using godaddy and getting a redirect loop

Comment: In case it helps someone - in order for `https://www.example.com` to redirect to `https://example.com` without an "untrusted" warning, I also needed to enter the custom SSL info into modulus twice, once for www and once for the naked domain. I used the same key and cert for each.